# Redux Form: How to add an image url to Redux Form before submitting it?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, axios

I have set up a form with file upload, where I upload an image to Cloudinary with separate request. What I want to do is to pick up an image url from the response Object from Cloudinary, pass it to my redux form and submit it all together with other form values to my server and database. So far my request looks like this

```
  onChange(event) {
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
   formData.append('upload_preset', UPLOAD_PRESET);

  axios({
    url: `${COUDINARY_ROOT_URL}`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: formData
    }).then((res) => {
     console.log(res);

   }).catch((err) => {
     console.err(err);
   });
```

My problem is, in what way can I add this image url data from response and pass it to my redux form before submitting it to my server?

If it is not an efficient way, would be really thankful for recommendations as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe redux form can only store state if you pass the data through a form component (e.g input tag, checkbox etc). But in this case you want to store the data to the store from a variable. I'm not aware of any means through redux form, so I recommend that you use redux instead.

Also, if you are saving the image url for the sole purpose of making another request to send both url and form data to your server and database, it is actually not necessary to save it in the redux store. You can just return it so that you can use it in the next promise chain, as shown in my code below.

But, if you still insist on saving it to the store perhaps for some other reason, what I would do is dispatch an action that saves the url in my redux store.

```js
getImageUrl(formData) {
  return axios({
    url: `${COUDINARY_ROOT_URL}`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: formData
  });
}

sendDataToServer(url, formData) {
  // ... send url and formData to my server
}

onChange(event) {
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
 formData.append('upload_preset', UPLOAD_PRESET);
 getImageUrl(formData)
  .then(res => {
    // assuming res.url contains the url and
    // saveUrl is a method wrapped in dispatch from
    // mapDispatchToProps
    this.props.saveUrl(res.url);

    // return res.url so that it can be used in the 
    // next then chain
    return res.url;
  })
  .then(url => {
    // we can get the url from previous promise chain
    sendDataToServer(url, formData);

    // ... rest of code

  })
  .catch(err => console.err(err))

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about adding it to the store first.. But it wasn't really necessary, so I've moved it inside the component instead. Will try your approach, thank you so much once again! :)